# Child elements in ASP.NET TagHelper

Tags: asp.net, tag-helpers

I'm sure this is obvious but I can't seem to add a child html element to an ASP.NET TagHelper.

I'm trying to output the following

```
<li class=""><a href=""><i class="icon - list - alt"></i><span>Orders</span> </a> </li></html>
```

and have tried the following

```
output.TagName = "li";

var a = new TagBuilder("a");
a.MergeAttribute("href", $"{menuUrl}");
a.MergeAttribute("title", MenuText);
a.InnerHtml.Append(MenuText);                    

var b = new TagBuilder("i");
b.MergeAttribute("class", IconClass);
b.MergeAttribute("style", "font-size : 20px");

output.Content.Append(a);
output.Content.Append(b);
```

But this renders a separate "a" element to the "i" element, anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The code you've written should output something looking like `<li><a href="something" title="Menu Text Attribute">Menu Text Content</a><i class="random" style="font-size : 20px"></i></li>
` Is there more to your code that you're not showing?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Yes, there is some business logic missing but that doesn't effect the output which is <li><a href="/purchaseorder" title="Orders">Orders</a><i class="icon-list-alt" style="font-size : 20px"></i></li>